# How do I change my memorized spells?

Tags: neverwinter-nights-2

I made Elanee (druid) memorize a spell by error and I want to change it.

But it seems that once a spell is memorized there's no way to unlearn it! How can I remove/replace a spell from one of my memorized slots?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved, on my Macbook Pro, you need to have three fingers on the track pad and then click on a memorized spell to unlearn it. I suppose it's the same as a middle click.

Comment: You should just be able to right click...

Comment: nope. Right click on my computer shows me the spell characteristics.

Comment: I think it's something related to the implementation for the various OS

Comment: Yea on PCs with 2/3 buttons, right click would forget the spell.

Answer (score -2):

all you have to do is double click to unlearn